# How to overcome the single default export issue when using react-nav and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a button in my app that needs to navigate to another screen **and** change a value in redux simultaneously. Of course, `export default` cannot be used twice but - when I mark one of the exports as a constant, the code will fail. In this case, `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)` is failing. How can I get the two exports working?:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { person } from "../../assets/people";
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


export class ProfileCard extends Component {
    updateMarkerState = (x) => {
        this.props.updateMarkerState(x)
        this.props.navigation.navigate("map");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card >
                <CardItem cardBody>
                    <Image source={this.props.data.values.photoId} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
                </CardItem>
                <CardItem>
                    <Text>{this.props.data.values.altName}</Text>
                </CardItem>
                <CardItem>
                    <Text>{this.props.data.values.personIntroText}</Text>
                </CardItem>
                <CardItem style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Button transparent
                            onPress={() =>
                                this.updateMarkerState(this.props.data.values.id)
                            }>
                            <Icon active name="pin" />
                        </Button>
                            <Button transparent
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.props.navigation.navigate("YouTubeScreen", {id: this.props.data.values.id});
                                }}>
                            <Icon active name="play"/>
                        </Button>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateMarkerState: (id) => {
        dispatch(updateMarkerState(id))
      }
    }
}

export const conn =  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileCard)

export default withNavigation(ProfileCard);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate HOCs, like

```
export default withNavigation(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileCard));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting `updateMarkerState is not defined`, though.

Comment: what do you normally pass to connect?

Comment: `export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileCard)`

Comment: Well, I copied it over from another from another component :) ... do you know of any documentation on concatenate HOCs?

Comment: I'm not surprised that it's breaking, since I copied it.

Comment: the part that makes me get confused is that connect with a null as parameter has worked once

Comment: Thanks for helping me think this through, Bruno. I've got it now - I had not imported the action `updateMarkerState` from my `./actions/index.js.`